# Counting the number of columns in the database

Tags: mysql, sql

I've been trying to count the number of columns in a table in my database using the below statement:

```
    rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name = '"+TableName+"'");
            while (rs.next()) {
               i = rs.getInt(1);
    }
```

For the below table table this code returns "6". If it only counts the columns it must return 3 and if it count columns of all record the returned value must be 12. My question is how come I get the 6 value.

```
|Username|   |Password|   |Level|
|Admin   |   |Admin   |   |1    |
|User    |   |User    |   |2    |
|Staff   |   |Staff   |   |3    |
|User1   |   |User1   |   |2    |
```

And how can I properly count the columns of a table ?

Comment: sqlinjection detected

Comment: @nachokk: yes, you are right, it doesn't matter it is not a serious application.

Comment: did you debug it? in sqlclient returns the same sql as in java?

Comment: @nachokk: I should get 12 but I have no idea why it returns 6, the phpmyadmin returns the same value.

Comment: then it's not a java problem, should remove tag

Comment: Maybe also specify the db? 
..FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_schema = 'myDB'  ...

Comment: @Mihai consider making that as an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following query returns the number of columns that you have. If you want to get 12 you would have to multiply by the number of rows in the table:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`COLUMNS` 
WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA`='Yourdatabase' 
    AND `TABLE_NAME`='yourtable';
```

See it in [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/794e8/6)

Comment: Thanks Filipe, I'll accept this answer as it worked very well.

Answer (score 1):

Also specify the db,you might have a table with the same name in other db

```
...FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_schema = 'myDB'...
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are working in java. 
You can also try this

```
rs = st.executeQuery("select * from "+TableName+" limit 1");
ResultSetMetaData metadata = rs.getMetaData();
int columnsNumber = metadata.getColumnCount();
```